# Does @transaction.atomic follow function calls

Tags: django, transactions, atomic

I want to confirm my theory. I was reading the docs, but maybe I am not reading correctly

Let's say we have

```
@transaction.atomic
def create(...):
    few queries...
    func_a()
    return

def func_a():
    also running few queries...
```

If queries fail inside `func_a` will transaction atomic rollback? I am trying to figure out if it wraps the whole execution flow or just the `create` function in this scenario.

Sorry if my question is a bit silly

Comment: You can also use the `with` keyword. `with transaction.atomic():`

Answer (score 0):

> If queries fail inside func_a will transaction atomic rollback?

Yes, Django will wrap all queries you perform, even inside functions calls.
In your example, if `func_a()` raise an exception to `create()`, it will make the transaction to rollback.

The docs atomic usage example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

```py
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
    # The function bellow executes inside a transaction.
    do_stuff()
# or
def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes in autocommit mode (Django's default).
    do_stuff()

    with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        do_more_stuff()
```